# Can I use webpack to bundle a Next.js custom server?

Tags: webpack, next.js

When you implement a custom server with Next.js it [isn't bundled in the production build](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server). My question is (before I try), can a [custom webpack config](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) be used to bundle it?

My reason for wanting to do this is that I don't want to ship code in the production build.

***EDIT:** I'm working with Next.js 7.0.2 and Webpack 4.20.2 which is used by that. So [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/7.0.2#customizing-webpack-config) is the right link for customising the webpack config for that version.*

Comment: Hey, when you say a custom server "isn't bundled in the product build", do you mean it isn't deployable to Vercel? I'm asking because "bundling" generally refers to transforming the code that's sent to the client.

Comment: Also can you clarify what you mean by "I don't want to ship code in the production build"? Maybe give an example?

Comment: By "isn't bundled in the product build", I mean the back-end Express code doesn't get bundled by webpack into the .next folder when you run next build. By "I don't want to ship code in the production build", I mean I want to bundle the server-side code with webpack too because we need to pass the docker image containing the app to a thirdparty.

Comment: You could write a short script that moves the server code into the .next folder after the build completes. And then add it to your package.json like `build: next export && copy_server.sh`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so having experimented, it turns out you can add another entry to the existing Next.js webpack config but because the custom server needs different settings it's actually better to do it separately. I now have a `build-server` script that bundles the custom server to a folder called `.server`. I also added obfuscation to both that and the Next.js webpack config.

Here's my `next-config.js`:

```js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator')

module.exports = withCSS({
    poweredByHeader: false,
    webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            // Extend default config with obfuscation
            config.plugins.push(
                new WebpackObfuscator ({
                    rotateStringArray: true
                })
            )
        }

        // Important: return the modified config
        return config
    }
})
```

And here's my `webpack.config.server.js`:

```js
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator')

// Config to build Express server and associated server-side code bundle
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    entry: './server/server.js',
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // Ignore node_modules
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.server'),
        filename: 'server.bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        // Obfuscate the code
        new WebpackObfuscator ({
            rotateStringArray: true
        })
    ]
}
```

The `build-server` script is:

```bash
"build-server": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.server.js"
```

Comment: Could you kindly share your findings?

Comment: Apologies - I totally forgot to do this. Answer updated.